# Simulation done/finished event in jNeuroML?

Tags: biological-neural-network, neuron-simulator, neuroml, lems

Is there some event mechanism that could let me know if the simulation is finished?

I have a LEMS file that is simulated in NEURON with:

`jnml LEMS_file.xml -neuron -run`

the GUI stays open after the simulation is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least with LEMS -> NEURON simulations, the `-nogui` flag will run the simulation till the end and then close NEURON.

`jnml LEMS_file.xml -neuron -run -nogui`

Any commands after this one will be executed after the simulation is finished.